# LVM internal error: LV segments corrupted after adding a stripe to a raid5 LV

Tags: lvm

I am trying to simulate a planned upgrade to a storage system. For this, i recreated the setup with smaller disks in a VM.

**Preparation**

The starting point is a LV with raid5, 2 stripes across 3 PVs, and caching on a single PV, setup as follows:

pvcreate /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
   vgcreate vg01 /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
   lvcreate -n origin_lv -l 8180 -i 2 --type raid5 vg01 \
      /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf

which results in a VG with raid5 across 3 devices. I then did this to create the cache volumes:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc1
vgextend vg01 /dev/sdc1
lvcreate -n origin_lv_cache -L 10G vg01 /dev/sdc1


pvcreate /dev/sdc2
vgextend vg01 /dev/sdc2
lvcreate -n origin_lv_cache_meta -L 1G vg01 /dev/sdc2
```

this to create the cache pool:

```
lvconvert \
   --type cache-pool \
   --poolmetadata vg01/origin_lv_cache_meta \
   vg01/origin_lv_cache
```

and attached it to the origin LV:

```
lvconvert \
     --type cache \
     --cachepool vg01/origin_lv_cache \
     vg01/origin_lv

>>>> output: "Logical volume vg01/origin_lv is now cached"
```

I then do luksFormat and mkfs, resulting in a perfectly mountable filesystem.

**The Problem**

Now, I want to add capacity. To do this, I've tried the following:

```
lvconvert --splitcache vg01/origin_lv
```

to remove the caching. This syncs everything from the cache to the actual LV, then I can do this:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdg 
vgextend vg01 /dev/sdg
```

to add the new PV, then:

lvconvert --stripes 3 vg01/origin_lv [all previous devices] [new device]

this results in a LV with 50% more space, as expected. Now I tried reattaching the cache, and even removing the cache volumes and recreating them, but when I try to reattach it to the actual LV, I get this:

```
lvconvert \
    --type cache-pool \
    --poolmetadata vg01/origin_lv_cache_meta \
    vg01/origin_lv_cache
```

> output:

```
Do you want wipe existing metadata of cache pool vg01/origin_lv_cache? [y/n]: y
  LV origin_lv, segment 1 invalid: reshape for cache segment.
  Internal error: LV segments corrupted in origin_lv.
```

However, I can mount and read/write the underlying LV just fine, it just doesn't work to reattach the cache.

any ideas what i am missing here?

Comment: Normally the block devices are encrypted first, then the LVM volumes created using the encrypted block devices as PVs. You have done it in the reverse order. This might or might not be the cause of the immediate problem, but it might also cause other problems (such as possibly being unbootable). If you aren't precisely replicating an environment where these were created reversed, I would recommend un-reversing it.

Comment: hi @michael-hampton. i am replicating an existing environment, to figure out how to upgrade it (and if it is possible). as for the order of luks, mkfs and lvm ... it is what it is, but i would think that underneath the mkfs its all a blockdevice anyways, no? how would this make a difference here? for all LVM knows, it might be used for (heavens beware) NTFS ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, fsresize is not aware of the underlying sync status. Using lvs to check the sync status and waiting for 100% synced, then resizing worked just fine.

Comment: Which OS? Having exactly the same issue, waiting till 100% sync doesn't help.